# breadth-first search in C language

Tags: c, algorithm

I have two integer lists say list_a and list_b.
I have a function say `func()`, and `func(list_a)` would produce n lists say:

```
list_a_1   list_a_2  list_a_3   list_a_4 ........... list_a_n
```

I have to run `func()` on all lists as produced above until I find one of those lists = `list_b`.

So below could be the possible representation of how the list grows:

```
                                 list_a

============================================================================

list_a_1   list_a_2  list_a_3   list_a_4 ........... list_a_n    LEVEL 1

============================================================================

list_a_1_1.... list_a_1_n    list_a_2_1... list_a_2_n.....      LEVEL 2

============================================================================
```

Suppose say we find list_a_1_n == list_b, then stop the function and return the LEVEL, which in our case is 2 (Level2).

I am not being able to do it :(

**How to do it in C?**

Please note, this is not a homework question.

I am trying to find Cyclic Kendal Tau distance between two inputs as I think I found a solution in terms of algorithm for [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_approach_algorithm_to_find_cyclic_Kendal_Tau_distance) question. I want to check whether my algorithm is correct.

below is the code in Python:

```
import collections


def Transpose(alist):
    leveloutput = []
    n = len(alist)
    for i in range(n):
        x=alist[:]
        x[i],x[(i+1)%n] = x[(i+1)%n],x[i]
        leveloutput.append(x)
    return leveloutput


def Cyc_Ken_Tau(start, goal):
    queue = collections.deque([(start, 0)])

    while True:
        element, level = queue.popleft()
        if element == goal:
            return level
        for new_list in Transpose(element):
            queue.append((new_list, level + 1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "***********************************************************"

    u = [2, 3, 4, 1]
    v = [1, 2, 4, 3]

    print "***********************************************************"

    m = Cyc_Ken_Tau(u,v)
    print "Cyclic Kendal Tau:",m
```

Also the partial code in C is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_array(int **a, int num_elements);
int **transpose(int n, int arr[n]);

int main(){
    int a[] = {2, 3, 4, 1};
    int **c;
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
    int i;
    printf("original\n");
    print_array2(a,4);
    printf("\n*****************************\n");
    c= transpose(n, a);
    print_array(c, n);
    //deallocate
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        free(c[i]);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}

int **transpose(int n, int arr[n]){
    int l = n;
    int **b = malloc(l * sizeof(*b));//sizeof(*b) : sizeof(int *)
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        j = (i + 1) % l;
        int *copy = malloc(l * sizeof(*copy));//sizeof(int)
        for (k = 0; k < l; k++)
            copy[k] = arr[k];
        int t = copy[i];
        copy[i] = copy[j];
        copy[j] = t;
        //printf("{%d, %d, %d, %d}\n", copy[0], copy[1], copy[2], copy[3]);
        b[i] = copy;
    }
    return b;
}

void print_array(int **a, int num_elements){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<num_elements; i++){
        for(j=0; j<num_elements; j++)
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_array2(int a[], int num_elements)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
   {
     printf("%d ", a[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

But I am struggling with the **Cyc_Ken_Tau** function in C. Any help will be much much appreciated.

Comment: the returned value from malloc (and family) should always be checked to assure successful operation.

Comment: can you post a link to the Cyc_Ken_Tau function?

Comment: In python it works, But since I am not good, I am not being able to convert the same code in C. What I meant was Cyc_Ken_Tau function from Python  code.

Comment: Why recursive?  BFS requirrs a queue, not a stack, so recursion is not really natural. (And why C? In c++ the standard library implements  deque, so the solution would be much smaller.)

Comment: Since most of the other testing programs have been written in C, I would prefer to seek help for c, as otherwise incompatible. :(

Comment: @Technopolice: That doesn't explain why you want it to be recursive. If you do it in C, you'll need to implement a queue of lists, and then you can just about use your python code as is. In C++, of course, it's the same, except that you don't need to implement `std::deque<std::array<int, 4>>` (or `std::deque<std::vector<int>>` if you don't know the size of the lists at compile time), so that's a lot less code.